# Error al Conectarme a MySQL con PHP y Peticiones AJAX

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

Me encuentro en un dilema, hasta el momento me ha funcionado el código de tal manera que no me retorna nada y al retornar la información de ejecutar la conexión y la sentencia SQL me retorna espacios nulos.

```
<?php 

    require_once "../../clases/Conexion.php";
    require_once "../../clases/Clientes.php";
    require_once "../../clases/Articulos.php";

    $c = new conectar();
    $conexion = $c->conexion();

 ?>

<h4 class="mt-3">Vender un Producto</h4>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <form action="" id="frmVentasDeProductos">
            <label for="Cliente">Cliente</label>
            <select class="form-control form-control-sm" id="cliente" name="cliente">
                <option value="A">Selecciona una Opción</option>
                <option value="0">Sin Cliente</option>
                <?php 

                    $sql = "SELECT id_cliente, nombre, apellido FROM clientes";

                    $result = mysqli_query($conexion, $sql);

                    while($r = mysqli_fetch_row($result)) :
                 ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $r[0] ?>"><?php echo $r[1] ?> <?php echo $r[2] ?></option>
                <?php endwhile; ?>
            </select>
            <label for="Artículo">Artículo</label>
            <select class="form-control form-control-sm" id="producto" name="producto">
                <option value="A">Selecciona una Opción</option>
                <?php 
                    $sql = "SELECT id_articulo, nombre FROM articulos";

                    $result = mysqli_query($conexion, $sql);

                    while($r = mysqli_fetch_row($result)) :
                 ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $r[0] ?>"><?php echo $r[1] ?></option>
                <?php endwhile; ?>
            </select>
            <label for="Descripción">Descripción</label>
            <textarea readonly="" name="descripcion" id="descripcion" class="form-control"></textarea>
            <label for="Cantidad">Cantidad</label>
            <input readonly="" type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" id="cantidad" name="cantidad">
            <label for="Precio">Precio</label>
            <input readonly="" type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" id="precio" name="precio">
            <span class="btn btn-primary btn-sm btn-block mt-2" id="btnAgregarVenta">Agregar</span>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
        <div class="" id="imagen_articulo"></div>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#producto').change(function(){
            $.ajax({
                type:"POST",
                data:"id_articulo=" + $('#producto').val(),
                url:"../procesos/ventas/llenarFormProducto.php",
                success:function(r){
                    console.log(r);
                    // dato=jQuery.parseJSON(r);

                    // $('#descripcionV').val(dato['descripcion']);
                    // $('#cantidadV').val(dato['cantidad']);
                    // $('#precioV').val(dato['precio']);

                    // $('#imgProducto').prepend('<img class="img-thumbnail" id="imgp" src="' + dato['ruta'] + '" />');
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>

<!-- Script Select 2 -->
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#cliente').select2();
        $('#producto').select2();
    });
</script>
```

Ya se agregó el código junto con la petición AJAX

Aquí esta el código del SCRIPT, donde va a realizar la petición AJAX cada vez que cambie, la petición la realiza al archivo llenarFormProducto.php e imprimo a trávez de la consola lo que contiene la variable r que llega como parámetro

```
require_once "../../clases/Conexion.php";
require_once "../../clases/Ventas.php";

$obj= new ventas();

echo json_encode($obj->obtenDatosProducto($_POST['id_articulo']));
```

En este archivo incluyo los archivos Conexion.php y Ventas.php, a su vez, creo un nuevo objeto de la clase ventas() y llamo a su función obtenerDatosProducto(), que lleva por un parámetro el ID del producto del ComboBox, y lo imprimo en formato json

```
<?php 

    class ventas
    {

        public function obtenDatosProducto($id_articulo)
        {
            $c = new conectar();
            $conexion=$c->conexion();

            $sql="SELECT art.nombre,
            art.descripcion,
            art.cantidad,
            img.ruta,
            art.precio 
            from articulos as art 
            inner join imagenes as img
            on art.id_imagen=img.id_imagen 
            AND art.id_articulo='$id_articulo'";
            $result=mysqli_query($conexion,$sql);
            // $ver=mysqli_fetch_row($result);
            // $d=explode('/', $ver[3]);
            // $img=$d[1].'/'.$d[2].'/'.$d[3].''.$d[4];
            // $data=array(
            //  'nombre' => $ver[0],
            //  'descripcion' => $ver[1],
            //  'cantidad' => $ver[2],
            //  'ruta' => $img,
            //  'precio' => $ver[4]
            // );       
            return $result;
        }
    }
```

Aquí se encuentra la función donde ejecuto la snetencia SQL y creo un nuevo objeto de la clase conexión y al momento de retornar lo que contiene la variable $result = mysqli_query($conexion, $sql);

Me sale lo siguiente
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Es algo que no entiendo, vengo trabajando de la misma manera, pero en el módulo de ventas me persiste este error, intenté registrar más registros de otros módulos y siguen funcionando correctamente.
Desconozco la razón del porque me retorna todos los campos nulos.

Una cosa que me falto agregar la estructura de mis archivos
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Si no me equivoco, al regresarte el objeto esta obtiendo respuesta de tu ajax, podrias revisar si al hacer la misma consulta sql en el PHPMYADMIN te regresa algun dato? para asi descartar a la bbdd, tambien revisar que datos te regresa el $result

Comment: De echo ya probe mis sentencias SQL en WorkBench, y funcionan correctamente, aquí no entiendo lo que pasa

Comment: Te sugiero que evites publicar imagenes, debido a que tu codigo no puede ser copiado o editado facilmente, para poder reproducir tu error. 

http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode/

Comment: Alan, trata de publicar el codigo escrito, en la caja de edicion tienes unas { } donde puedes convertir tu codigo a un snippet.
trata de hacer lo siguiente, en tu php hazle un echo al $result o al objeto final resultante que en este caso seria tu data no? para ver como queda dividido

Comment: @BrianJerez esta genial ese sitio

Comment: Graciasm ya edité la pregunta, espero me puedan ayudar, ya ando desesperado por ese error

Comment: @BrianJerez https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2868/por-qu%C3%A9-he-recibido-un-voto-negativo/2869#2869

Comment: @BrianJerez ya corregí la pregunta, ya agregué mejor los códigos

Comment: juntos podemos hacer de stackoverflow un mejor lugar!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A tu método `obtenDatosProductos()` le falta recuperar los resultados, pues lo que tú devuelves actualmente es un objeto [`mysqli_result`](http://php.net/manual/es/class.mysqli-result.php) .

Para almacenar los resultados y devolverlos puedes hacer algo como esto:

**Este código debe ir en `obtenDatosProductos()`. Debes quitar la variable `$result` que tienes y el `return $result`**, poniendo esa parte así:

```
$arrDatos=array();
if ($result = mysqli_query($conexion, $sql)) {
    /* obtener array asociativo */
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $arrDatos[]=$row;
    }
}else{

    $arrDatos["error"]=mysqli_error($conexion);
}

return $arrDatos;
```

Comment: El problema es que en la variable $result, no me manda nada, porque me aparece todo nulo en los campos de la consola

Comment: @AlanAmauryEscobedoGarcía Lo que mostraba el `console.log` de la imagen posteada al principio era un objeto `mysqli_result`, cuyos datos son: `current_field, field_count, lengths, num_rows`.  (ver enlace en mi respuesta). El que todo sea nulo puede deberse a que hay problemas con la conexión, con la consulta o que la consulta que le estás enviando no encontrando datos con los criterios solicitados. ¿Probaste a  corregir el método `obtenDatosProductos()` como he indicado más arriba?

Comment: Entonces, si muestra eso, creo la conexión en el archivo para probar si es que funciona en el archivo Ventas.php ?

Comment: En todo caso, aunque la conexión funcione, no obtendrás los datos de la consulta si dejas al método `obtenDatosProductos()` como lo tienes, por lo que acabo de explicarte. Ese método no recupera los resultados de la consulta en sí, sino que te devuelve un objeto `mysqli_result`.  Ahora bien, el que diga que todo es `null` indica que hay otro problema en alguna parte del código.

Comment: @AlanAmauryEscobedoGarcía he editado la respuesta, poniendo un `else` que te informará sobre el error que pueda estar ocurriendo.

Comment: Gracias, en base a lo que me compartiste y mediante el else y el ciclo While para el ciclo asociativo, me sirvió de mucha ayuda :D